# Can I use free Visual Studio Community to develop commercial application?

Tags: visual-studio

I am looking to build serverless application with .Net Core. Visual Studio will be a good choice.

Could the Community be used to develop commercial application? (not individual developers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Community for commercial project outside windows store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816702/visual-studio-community-for-commercial-project-outside-windows-store)

Comment: SO is not a good place to be asking legal questions - you should read the license yourself https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/vs2022-ga-community/